# Does AWS MemoryDB supports Redis Search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, json-path-expression, amazon-memory-db

I'm planning to use AWS MemoryDB for reading and filtering out data from my JSON document using JSON commands https://docs.aws.amazon.com/memorydb/latest/devguide/json-document-overview.html
I was able to perform search operations and get back data using JSON.SET and JSON.GET.
I would like to know if we can perform JSON string search operations similar to LIKE operator we have in RDS. Any pointers around this would be helpful

References
https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/